# Capturar o valor do item selecionado no selectOneRadio com JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, primefaces

Tenho esse componente Primefaces:

```
<p:selectOneRadio id="mercado" styleClass="teste">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Interno" itemValue="I"/>
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Externo" itemValue="E"/>
</p:selectOneRadio>
```

Tentei capturar o valor da seleção via JavaScript conforme abaixo, mas ele retorna vazio.

```
$('.teste').change(function () {
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

Como faço para recuperar o valor da seleção via JavaScript?

Código completo do formulário:

```
<!-- Dialog com Formulario de Produtos-->
<p:dialog header="Formulário de Produtos" widgetVar="dialogProdutos" resizable="false" modal="true">
  <h:form id="formCadClientes">
    <p:panelGrid columns="2" id="painel" columnClasses="rotulo, campo" style="margin-top: 20px; margin-bottom: 20px">
      <p:outputLabel value="Código" for="codigo" />
      <p:panelGrid columns="2" styleClass="semBorda">
        <p:inputText id="codigo" size="20" />
      </p:panelGrid>
      <p:outputLabel value="Descrição" for="descricao" />
      <p:panelGrid columns="2" styleClass="semBorda">
        <p:inputText id="descricao" size="70" />
      </p:panelGrid>
      <p:outputLabel value="Categoria" for="categoria" />
      <p:panelGrid columns="2" styleClass="semBorda">
        <p:selectOneMenu id="categoria" style="width: 230px">
          <f:selectItem itemLabel="Selecione uma categoria" />
        </p:selectOneMenu>
        <p:commandButton value="+" oncomplete="PF('dialogCategorias').show();" title="Adicionar nova categoria" style="height: 30px" />
      </p:panelGrid>
      <p:outputLabel value="Mercado" for="mercado" />
      <p:panelGrid columns="2" styleClass="semBorda">
        <p:selectOneRadio id="mercado" styleClass="teste">
          <f:selectItem itemLabel="Interno" itemValue="I" />
          <f:selectItem itemLabel="Externo" itemValue="E" />
        </p:selectOneRadio>
      </p:panelGrid>
      <p:outputLabel value="Preço" for="preco" />
      <p:panelGrid columns="2" styleClass="semBorda">
        <p:inputText id="preco" size="15" />
      </p:panelGrid>
      <p:outputLabel value="Moeda" for="moeda" />
      <p:panelGrid columns="2" styleClass="semBorda">
        <p:inputText id="moeda" size="15" />
      </p:panelGrid>
      <p:outputLabel value="Imposto" for="imposto" />
      <p:panelGrid columns="2" styleClass="semBorda">
        <p:inputText id="imposto" size="15" />
      </p:panelGrid>
    </p:panelGrid>
    <p:commandButton value="Gravar" icon="ui-icon-disk" style="width: 120px; height: 40px; font-size: 16px" />
    <p:commandButton value="Cancelar" icon="ui-icon-cancel" oncomplete="PF('dialogProdutos').hide();" style="width: 120px; height: 40px; font-size: 16px" />
  </h:form>
</p:dialog>
```

Segue imagem do formulário renderizado:

[image: Imagem do formulário renderizado]

Basicamente o que eu gostaria é que quando selecionar o Interno, no campo moeda seja setado o valor "R$" se selecionar o Externo, seja setado o valor "US$".

Comment: Sim, estão dentro de um <h:form></h:form>

Comment: Perfeito! funcionou direitinho, vlw pela ajuda!!!

Comment: Pode claro... Imagino! vlw msm...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insira `onchange="teste(this.value)"` (ou `onclick="teste(this.value)"`) em `<p:selectOneRadio id="mercado" styleClass="teste">`, ficando assim:

```
<p:selectOneRadio id="mercado" styleClass="teste" onchange="teste(this.value)">
```

E a função em JavaScript que receberá o valor:

```
<script>
function teste(a){
    alert('O valor do radio clicado é '+a);
}
</script>
```